# Mathematica: Constraints not valid Nmaximize

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, constraints

I am trying to use NMaximize in Mathematica
This is how I proceeded:

1) define a list of parameters: `Par = {a->1, b->3, etc};`

2) define two functions: `f1: v1=express./Par  f2: v2=express./Par`

After this the expression are numerical except for the variables:

```
V1=f(e1,x) and V2=f(e2,x)
```

The objective function to be maximized is `V1/(e1+e2)`
I defined the constraint as `constr=V1-V2;`

then I used the NMaximize:

```
 NMaximize[{objopt > 0, constr == 0}, {e1, e2, x}, Method -> NelderMead]
```

I obtained the following error:

> NMaximize::bcons: "The following constraints are not valid:
>   "expression". Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or
>   domain specifications involving the variables"

I checked that only those variables are present in the constraint and objective function (other are numerical parameters).
I do not understand why this error appears.

Comment: Please post a complete, self-contained and minimal example showing the behavior

Comment: No need to maximize the expression "objopt>0". 'True' is as high as it's going to be, if ever.

Comment: I am a real Noob with mathematica. I made several mistakes. The first was to express the objective as a constrain. I Realized how to fix the many error I made. Thank you guys for the availability. See for the next question I will have.